# How to call functions & variables from other JS files in panel - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

There are two scripts (script1.js and script2.js) in my panel.html. Is there any way to call functions from script2.js in script1.js?

They are actually in same environment (Devtools panel). Why does my call fail, when i try to call a function in other script? Am i missing something?

Comment: There could be dozens of things you've done wrong so the question needs [MCVE](/help/mcve), otherwise it'll be a wild goose chase of random guesses.

Comment: i loaded the script1 after script2. i was doing that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you load `script2.js` before `script1.js` in your `panel.html` file and that should work

Comment: Glad to know if that resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ‘export default’ the function?

```
 export default function fnc(){}
```

Then import it Ej:

```
Import * as F from ‘script1’
F.fnc()
```